# Error in converting a string to python date-time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(['12/4/1982']))
```

However with this, I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 1053, in to_datetime
    result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, utc)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 1161, in _assemble_from_unit_mappings
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 1161, in <dictcomp>
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}
               ^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 1156, in f
    if value.lower() in _unit_map:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Could you please help to understand what was wrong with my code?

Comment: If `arg` of `to_date_time` is a `DatFrame`  the method expects minimally the following columns: "year", "month", "day"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supplying whole dataframe to [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime). In this case (from the documentation):

> ... If a DataFrame is provided, the method expects minimally the following columns: "year", "month", "day". The column “year” must be specified in 4-digit format.

Try this instead:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["12/4/1982"])
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           0
0 1982-12-04
```